# iOS: Swipe left/right between tabs possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to swipe left or right anywhere on the screen to switch tabs in iOS? Thanks

Example 1: Switching between months on a calender by simply swiping left/right
Example 2: start at 0:12 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iX4vcsSst8

Answer (score 20):

If you are using a tab bar controller, you could set up a swipe gesture recognizer on each tab's view. When the gesture recognizer is triggered, it can change the tabBarController.selectedTabIndex

This effect will not be animated, but it will switch the tabs with a swipe gesture. This was approximately what I used when I had an app with a UITabBar with buttons on the left and right side and swipe gestures to change the active tab.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedRightButton:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedLeftButton:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (IBAction)tappedRightButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [rootVC.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex + 1];
} 

- (IBAction)tappedLeftButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [rootVC.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex - 1]; 
}
```

Comment: So it would not be possible to animate like in the Android youtube example in the original post?

Comment: I've created a more fluid tab controls in the past and it was a much more custom solution than the tab bar example above. The last time I did something like that, I created a really long view controller that contained all of the section view controllers laid out side by side (I had 5 sections, so that VC was 5x the screen width). Navigation involved sliding the container VC left and right. It's not the best method as all VCs stay in memory at all times, but it's the best I could get for what I needed it for. I can't show any code snippets from that one unfortunately.

Comment: As of iOS7, it is possible to use `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` with a custom view controller transition to accomplish this effect. Basically you'll have a navigation controller with a custom push/pop animation to do the sliding. The UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition will allow the transition to track as a pan rather than as a swipe.

Comment: what is tappedRightButton and tappedLeftButton? I don't want any buttons, just a swipe like Android has BY DEFAULT in page views...

Comment: @Radu, I believe I pulled that code from an example where I had the swipe gestures and buttons at the left and right edges to advance tabs. The naming of the method really doesn't matter, the important part is setting the action method on the swipe gesture recognizers and adding the gesture recognizers to the view. iOS and Android tab bars are not identical. Having a fluid swipe from tab to tab isn't necessarily expected behavior on iOS. If you're looking for a more page based layout, this may not be the solution you want. See `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are using `UITabBarConroller`

All your child ViewControllers can inherit from a class that does all the heavy lifting for you.

This is how I have done it

```
class SwipableTabVC : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwipeLeft))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwipeRight))
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    func onSwipeLeft() {
        let total = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers!.count - 1
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = min(total, tabBarController!.selectedIndex + 1)

    }

    func onSwipeRight() {
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = max(0, tabBarController!.selectedIndex - 1)
    }
}
```

With this, all the viewcontrollers that are part of UITabController must inherit from `SwipableTabVC` instead of UIViewController.

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedRightButton:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedLeftButton:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (IBAction)tappedRightButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex + 1];

    //To animate use this code
    CATransition *anim= [CATransition animation];
    [anim setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [anim setDuration:1];
    [anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"fadeTransition"];
} 

- (IBAction)tappedLeftButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex - 1]; 

    CATransition *anim= [CATransition animation];
    [anim setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];

    [anim setDuration:1];
    [anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"fadeTransition"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend embedding the entire thing into a pageviewcontroller like so:
https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers

Comment: It would be very pleasure for me to check issues Richard KIM

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible.

Every screen would need to have a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`for the swipes, then make a call to the tab bar perform the desired action. Which could be anything from incrementing or decrementing the active tab to anything you want.

For the sake of code duplication prevention, you could create a custom `UIViewController` and have all your view controllers inherit from there (or a couple other ways).